# How to check if all substring in pandas column are the same?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have this [column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcbA7.png)
 and I want to check if all strings have `anr12` substring. How to check this? And if all substrings are the same, how to drop this particular substring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want check by [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html) for check all `True`s and then [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['123anr12', '345anr12']})
print (df)
          A
0  123anr12
1  345anr12

if df['A'].str.contains('anr12').all():
    df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace('anr12','')
print (df)

     A
0  123
1  345
```

EDIT1: You can use `dictionary` for lookup:

```
train_df = pd.DataFrame({'477':['123nbf12', '34nbf12'], 
                         '479':['tt1', '32'], 
                         '482':['anr1234', '345anr12a12']})

obj_features = ['477', '479', '482'] #it's column names 
substring = ['nbf', 'tt1', 'anr12'] # get rid of 'nbf', 'tt1', 'anr12' substrings 
d = dict(zip(obj_features, substring))
print (d)
{'477': 'nbf', '479': 'tt1', '482': 'anr12'}

for k, v in d.items():
    if train_df[k].str.contains(v).all(): 
        train_df[k] = train_df[k].str.replace(v,'')         
print (train_df)
     477  479     482
0  12312  tt1      34
1   3412   32  345a12
```

Comment: Thank you! What if i want to do it with 3 columns and difference values of substring? Is it a way do not duplicate a code?

Comment: @DmytroFedoriuk - Not sure if understand, can you use `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['123anr12', '345anr12'], 'B':['122', '32'], 'C':['123gs2', '345aaa12']})` and edit it and also add expected output?

Comment: I have 3 columns. One of it is with 'anr' value, second with 'tt1' value and third with 'rew' value. I just want to check if all values in each column have the same values. I'll do it with a loop. Thank you.

Comment: values for check are in list?

Comment: That how I've dealt with it.

`obj_features = ['477', '479', '482'] #it's column names
substring = ['nbf', 'tt1', 'anr12']
# get rid of 'nbf', 'tt1', 'anr12' substrings
for i in range(len(obj_features)):
    if train_df[obj_features[i]].str.contains(substring[i]).all():
        train_df[obj_features[i]] = train_df[obj_features[i]].str.replace(substring[i],'')`

Comment: Thank you! It's realy helpful.

Comment: @DmytroFedoriuk - Glad can help!